# How do I use a look up table to reflect certain outputs?

Tags: javascript

I would like to render certain strings based on how many agents they have... for example.

Tier 1:
1-4 agents

Tier 2:
5-9 agents

Tier 3:
10+ agents

---

If a user has 4 agents...
It should render "**TIER 1**
1 more agents to access Tier 2"

IF a user has 6 agents...
it should render "**TIER 2**
4 more agents to access Tier 3"

If a user has more then 10 agents...
It should render "**TIER 3**
You've reached the highest tier!"

```
currentTier(agentsCount) {
    if (agentsCount <= 4) {
        return 1;
    } else if (agentsCount >= 5 || agentsCount <= 9) {
        return 2;
    } else if (agentsCount >= 10) {
        return 3;
    }
}

nextTier(agentsCount) {
    let currentTier = this.currentTier(agentsCount);

    if (currentTier === 1) {
        return 2;
    } else if (currentTier === 2) {
        return 3;
    } else if (currentTier === 3) {
        return false;
    }
}

toNextTierMessage(agentsCount) {
    let nextTier = this.nextTier(agentsCount),
        toNextTier = 0;

    let currentTier = this.currentTier(agentsCount);
    if (currentTier === 1) {
        toNextTier = 5 - agentsCount;
    } else if (currentTier === 2) {
        toNextTier = 10 - agentsCount;
    }

    if (currentTier <= 2) {
        return toNextTier+ ' more agents to access Tier '+nextTier;
    } else if (currentTier >= 3) {
        return 'You\'ve reached the highest tier!';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having ?

Comment: Are you just trying to simplify the above?

Comment: The issue was on line 4 it should be && instead of || ... however. I was wondering if there is a better way of writing this code that's more simple and maintainable?

Comment: As my opinion, uses one function is enough. like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mpnLvot/)

Comment: if there are thousands of  tiers, it will be another story.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
function nextLevelMessage(agents) {
  return agents< 5?"TIER 1. "+( 5-agents)+" more agent(s) to access Tier 2.":
         agents<10?"TIER 2. "+(10-agents)+" more agent(s) to access Tier 3.":
                   "TIER 3. You've reached the highest tier!";
}
```

check for `0` or nothing passed for agents...

Comment: I see you like my answer - can you select and up-vote it, please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is less than 5 we have already returned 1 so no need to test again and if it is less than 10 we have already returned 2 so we can have a catch all for 3.

```
const currentTier = agentsCount => agentsCount <= 4 ? 1 : agentsCount <= 9 ? 2 : 3;
```